# Is it possible for a piece of music to be in multiple keys at the same time?

Tags: key

I was wondering if it is possible (would possibly sound good) to have a piece of music be using multiple keys simultaneously. For example having the melody use a different key to the harmony. Would this just sound awful or has it been done before?

Comment: Arguably, "Sweet Home Alabama" is in D or in G. Find the notes that would ruin the ambiguity — in the case of D and G, that would be F and F# — and either use neither or add in enough of both that it isn't clear. The fewer notes the scales have in common, the harder it would be to maintain ambiguity, I would guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible - in its fully-fledged form it's called [Polytonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytonality). Plenty of examples on that page.

Another less extreme technique that is more common but could still be described as 'multiple keys at the same time' is modal mixture - using chords and notes from two different keys with the same tonic (e.g. using chords and notes from F minor and F major in the same piece).

It is also possible for a chord progression to be tonally 'ambiguous', neither quite in one key or another (perhaps having the listener hear hints towards more than one tonic).

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a vague question, as most music can be seen to move from key to key. Example in key C, a piece may well *modulate* for a short time into, say, key Am, or key F. So, from that point of view, the answer's yes, multiple keys in one piece. Orchestral works are known to modulate into several keys other than their original from start to end.

But maybe that's not what you envisage. The Blues does this simultaneously. A piece in key A often contains notes from key A minor. It's the essence of Blues playing. As an aside, I sometimes get students to play a solo in key B♭ while I play in key C. It works o.k., as the B♭ and E♭ notes over C provide that Blues sound. As with even the diatonic notes, played in inappropriate places, they won't sound cohesive at best, good at worst.

On the same lines, a piece in, say, key A♭ *major* can move subtly into any **mode** of A♭ - A♭ Aeolian, A♭ Dorian. This entails retaining the same *root* but changing the feel by changing the other notes associated with that root.

Or, another ploy: keeping the same *notes* (as in C Ionian), but moving into D Dorian, F Lydian etc., a very common idea.

As far as playing an accompaniment in key A♭, and playing a melody in key B minor goes - well, in the hands of *real* musicians, it could work, but generally speaking, the results will be called cacophony - at least by myself.

Comment: This is a good answer but I'd say that if you force yourself into the western box you'll always come to this conclusion.  What about look at non-western music described in western terms?  That might not be fair but could yield example of music that seems to be in more than one key at the same time if for no other reason than the scale used covers two keys.

Answer (score 0):

i sometimes solo "off the 5th" or "off the 4th" in pentatonic scales . example being (in key of A) you can play D major pent, E major pent, D blues pent or E blues pent against the A and sound "fresher" (or at least interestingly different) as well as the A major pent and A blues pent against the A. playing a step below the root is the same as playing "off the 5th" when playing a step below the A major pent scale (it puts you playing in the E blues scale). however, it sounds awful to my ear when i'm playing a step below the blues scale. you are then playing a flat 3rd, a flat 7th, a flat 9 and an augmented 5th. maybe jazz guys would gig it, but i don't much care for it. i'm just an old blues and rock picker

Answer (score 0):

Check out **Fanfare for St Edmundsbury** by **Benjamin Britten**. Three trumpets, each playing in a different key. So clever.